# How to remove few objects from array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove one or few objects from array. Which meet the condition **completed === true**. Array can dynamically contain more or less objects.

```js
const array = [{
    completed: false,
    id: 1595572089666,
    title: "1"
  },
  {
    completed: false,
    id: 1595572089666,
    title: "2"
  },
  {
    completed: true,
    id: 1595572089666,
    title: "3"
  },
  {
    completed: true,
    id: 1595572089666,
    title: "4"
  },
  {
    completed: false,
    id: 1595572089666,
    title: "5"
  }
];

function removeCompleted(arr) {
  arr.reduce(item => {
    return item.completed === true ? item.splice(1, 1) : false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Array.prototype.filter()`? `const filtered = array.filter(({ completed }) => !completed)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Comment: From the duplicate, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20690490/283366)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` method to remove object based on `completed` property.

```js
let array = [{
    completed: false,
    id: 1595572089666,
    title: "1"
  },
  {
    completed: false,
    id: 1595572089666,
    title: "2"
  },
  {
    completed: true,
    id: 1595572089666,
    title: "3"
  },
  {
    completed: true,
    id: 1595572089666,
    title: "4"
  },
  {
    completed: false,
    id: 1595572089666,
    title: "5"
  }
];

array = array.filter(item => item.completed != true);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: i want remove items from existing array without creating new array

Comment: This will not create new array.    It will just overwrite existing array without using extra memory

Comment: _The [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method creates a **new** array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function._